# How should we behave for the "reference" questions?

Tags: discussion

Suppose user X comes in and ask "How is the group with professor Y at university Z ?". How should we treat this kind of questions ? One thing may be to answer with pure citation metrics, that is: they publish a lot, or they don't seem to. More personal experiences and opinions about Professor Y may trigger complaint from the professor him/herself.

Answer (score 12):

I think questions about specific people or specific departments are not good questions for this site.  It would be *much* better for the asker to directly contact students of the department/person in question.

Comment: This falls under the "too specific" guideline, and should be voted immediately as closed.